# error in user registration process of broadleaf commerce

Tags: user-registration, broadleaf-commerce

i configured broadleaf project with tomcat and the site module is up on running but when i go to register new user it will says like--please enter valid password and also by submit button user is successfully added in user when i go to admin panel i see the same user i registered but i can't login with that same user name and password that i provided while registration and it will give following errors--The e-mail address and/or password entered do not match our records. Please try again

Comment: the problem is not being solved till now please help

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in broadleaf commerce application.
It stores hashed password in the database, but when you login, it matches "clean" password with the hashed one. Therefore, you are getting "incorrect password".

### EDIT

Here are the exact steps to make it work.

**NOTE**: *I have used SHA-256 algorithm with salt as the username*

1. applicationContext-security.xml: Comment the following tags

```
    <sec:authentication-manager>...some stuff..</sec:authentication-manager>
```

2. In the same file, add the following:

```
    <bean id="blSaltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mdPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="256"/>
    </bean>
    <sec:authentication-manager alias="blAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="blUserDetailsService">
            <sec:password-encoder hash="sha-256" ref="mdPasswordEncoder">
                <sec:salt-source ref="blSaltSource" />
            </sec:password-encoder>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
```

3. Create a class to provide the object of SHA 256 algorithm.

```
public class CommonUtils {

            private static final ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);

            public static ShaPasswordEncoder getCustomerPasswordEncoder() {
                return encoder;
            }
    }
```

4. In the core module,  extend the CustomerServiceImpl and override the registerCustomer method.

```
public class MDCustomerServiceImpl extends CustomerServiceImpl {
    public Customer registerCustomer(Customer customer, String password, String passwordConfirm) {
      ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = CommonUtils.getCustomerPasswordEncoder();
      password = encoder.encodePassword(password, customer.getUsername());
      passwordConfirm = encoder.encodePassword(passwordConfirm, customer.getUsername());
      return super.registerCustomer(customer, password, passwordConfirm);
    }
}
```

5. In core module's applicationContext.xml, register your new service class.

   ```
   <bean id="blCustomerService" class="<path_to>MDCustomerServiceImpl" />
   ```
6. In RegisterController's processRegister, add the first line as:

```
    String unencodedPassword = registerCustomerForm.getPassword();
```

7. REPLACE

```
    loginService.loginCustomer(registerCustomerForm.getCustomer());
```

by

```
    String codedPassword = registerCustomerForm.getCustomer().getPassword();
    newCustomer.setUnencodedPassword(unencodedPassword)
    loginService.loginCustomer(newCustomer); 
    newCustomer.setUnencodedPassword(codedPassword);
    newCustomer.setPassword(codedPassword);
    customerService.saveCustomer(newCustomer);
```

This should make you good to go. :)

Comment: @YogeshDoke
i have updated my answer with exact steps. Please try these and they should work out for you.